# Combination Confusion - equal

Tags: combinatorics

I'm not understanding why the below are equal, can someone please explain?  Thanks!

$$\frac1{(1-x)^5}=\sum_{n\geq0}{n+4\choose 4}x^n$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Integrate this a bunch of times to get something that will look like

$$\operatorname{polynomial} + \operatorname{constant} \times \frac{1}{1-x}$$

Then express this in a power series, and differentiate a couple times.

Answer (score 1):

from Taylor formula for binomial $(1+x)^n=\sum_{i\geq0}\binom{n}{i}x^{i}$ that is valid for $n\in\mathbb Z$ follow
$$\frac1{(1-x)^5}=(1-x)^{-5}=\sum_{n\geq0}\binom{-5}{n}(-x)^n=\sum_{n\geq0}{n+4\choose 4}x^n$$
you need to prove that
$$(-1)^n\binom{-5}{n}=\binom{n+4}{4}$$